# How do I understand this compiler error: "multiple definition of ..."

Tags: c, linux, unix, gcc

I'm working on my exam assignment. It's due in almost 6 hours. Suddenly my program won't compile anymore with this error message:

```
gcc -g -D DEBUG -c -o obj/stringops.o src/stringops.c
gcc -g -D DEBUG -c -o obj/arrayops.o src/arrayops.c
gcc -g -D DEBUG -c -o obj/fileops.o src/fileops.c
gcc -g -D DEBUG -c -o obj/builtins.o src/builtins/*.c
gcc -g -D DEBUG -c -o obj/tomashell.o src/tomashell.c
gcc -g -D DEBUG -o bin/tomashell \
                obj/stringops.o obj/arrayops.o obj/fileops.o obj/builtins.o \
                obj/tomashell.o
obj/tomashell.o: In function `n_processes':
/root/sc/tomashell/src/safefork.c:11: multiple definition of `h_meta'
obj/builtins.o:/root/sc/tomashell/src/builtins/history.c:4: first defined here
obj/tomashell.o: In function `n_processes':
/root/sc/tomashell/src/safefork.c:11: multiple definition of `h_meta_len'
obj/builtins.o:/root/sc/tomashell/src/builtins/history.c:4: first defined here
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [bin/tomashell] Error 1
```

In this file:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/errno.h>

extern int errno;

#define MAX_PROCESSES 6

static int n_processes(void)
{ // <- THIS IS LINE 11
    return system("exit `ps | wc -l`")/256;
}


pid_t safefork(void)
{
  static int n_initial = -1;

  if (n_initial == -1)
    n_initial = n_processes();
  else if (n_processes() >= n_initial+MAX_PROCESSES) {
    sleep(2);
    errno = EAGAIN;  return (pid_t)-1;
  }

  return fork();
}
```

Someone please help me or kill me. I don't want to live in a world where this sort of error is possible.

Any ideas to what might be wrong?

[builtins/history.c](http://pastebin.com/2WjNHUDd)
[builtins/history.h](http://pastebin.com/BcNhSm6e)

Comment: can u post history.c file? (line 4)

Comment: I changed the title, it wasn't very constructive. Also, did you actually read the message? It looks quite clear.

Comment: [history.c](http://pastebin.com/2WjNHUDd)

Comment: Joe, the message tells me there are multiple definitions of `h_meta` on this line: `{`. What's clear about that? That sounds pretty impossible to me

Comment: Would `h_meta_len` and `h_meta` happen to be _defined_ in a shared .h file? Won't explain the line numbers, but will explain the error.

Comment: [history.h](http://pastebin.com/BcNhSm6e)

Comment: @eran, I have an include guard in place. In addition, the header is included only once

Comment: Include guards are per translation unit. If a few .c files include the same .h file, and that .h file contained a `int h_meta`, you'd have multiple definitions of `h_meta`. You should have the definition in one .c file, and an `extern int h_meta` in the .h file.

Comment: All well and good, but as I mentioned, the header is included only once. In addition, it's never included in safefork.c. Furthermore, both the lines in questions are curly brackets. I have still to hear an argument as to why this error is not impossible. How can we be sure hell is not freezing over, reality is inverting and space-time collapsing?

Comment: How is safefork.c getting built, anyway?  It's not referenced at all in the commands you posted...?

Comment: It's included in the main c file. I'll link it here: [tomashell.c](http://pastebin.com/LKxYXJXg)

Comment: @Codemonkey, you're looking at the raw files, not the preprocessor output.  Take a look at the lines after having been transformed by the preprocessor, either with gcc -E history.c or switch on gcc -save-temps and look at the resultant history.i file.

Comment: You #included a C file?  Stop that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like the others have said, you should not "define" (either implicitly or explicitly allocate space for) a variable in your headers.

This example might help:

```
#ifndef HISTORY
#define HISTORY
...

/* Bad!  Don't actually DEFINE (allocate space for) variables in a header!
 * h_metablock* h_meta = NULL;
 * int h_meta_len = 0;
 */

/* Better: declare "extern", then define in exactly ONE module (e.g. "main.c") */
extern h_metablock* h_meta;
extern int h_meta_len;
...
```

The same, of course, goes for any globals you might define in your .c/.cpp files.

A global can only be "defined" exactly *once*.

Answer (score 5):

As I've mentioned in my comment, the problem is with multiple definitions of `h_meta` and `h_meta_len` - be it due to them being defined in a .h file that's included in more than one translation unit, or due to .c (with the definition of the variables, either directly or in an included .h) being included in another .c. Include guards will save you from compilation errors, but not from link errors.

And this brings me to the weird error messages: You get those at **link time**. The linker operates on object files, which contain code from a .c file and all the files it had included. So, assuming `h_meta` and friend are not defined directly in two .c files, there's only so much the linker can do to provide you useful information. In VC, you'd only get a message telling you that there are multiple definitions, and the list of object files (rather than .c).

So, given the definitions come from files included in the mentioned .c files, there's no actual line number for the definitions. I guess GCC just defaults to the beginning of the source.

Comment: You have it exactly right. Without debug info, gcc (actually ld called from gcc) spits out `filename (.bss + 0xoffset)`. With debuginfo, it tries to convert that offset from the BSS into some source code line, and ends up printing a nonsensical line.

Comment: @ninjalj, I'm happy to hear my guestimation (always wanted to use that word...) was right. I've barely used gcc, and with VS you don't even get that much.

Answer (score 4):

Your header file `history.h` contains variable declarations. You must be including this file in multiple source files. This causes the variable to be declared multiple times. Instead you should either look into the `extern` keyword or reconsider your implementation.

Answer (score 1):

A program in C can have only one *definition* (declaration which assigns a value) for each object (storage space for a variable).

Your header file contains definitions for several variables, which when included in several different translation units results in the linker throwing this error. Your header file is included in at least two translation units, one for **history.c**, and another one for **tomashell.c**.

More information on what constitutes a definition [here](http://ninjalj.blogspot.com/2011/10/tentative-definitions-in-c.html).

Answer (score 0):

Compare safefork.c:11 and history.c:4

Looks like your symbol is being defined twice.

Comment: You may well fine that you've got the same thing included in each of those.

Comment: Both line 11 in safefork.c and line 4 in history.c is `{`.